# The message isn't shown in full length in html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There's a password-generating function on a password-generating website which always displays password in full length if I use alert(). But sometimes it doesn't show the generated password in its full length if I use element.html() or element.innerHTML.

If I click 'generate' button for about twenty times at least once the password I get is only 2 or 4 characters instead of 16.`enter code here`

```js
function rand(min, max) {
  var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
}

function generate() {
  var result = [];
  var characters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'm', 'n', 'l', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'M', 'N', 'L', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '`', '~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '=', '+', '[', ']', '{', '}', '\\', '|', '"', '\'', ';', ':', '/', '?', '<', '>'];
  for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    result[i] = characters[rand(0, 91)];
  var m = result.toString().replace(/,/g, '');
  $('#password').html(m);
  console.clear()
  console.log(m, ' len= ' , m.length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="generate" onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
<div id="password">Your password</div>
```

Comment: Converted to runnable stack snippet to run here in page and changed alert to `console.log(m.length)` and can not reproduce problem. Logs 16 every time

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have `<`character in your password. It's treated as part of incomplete html tag. You should use `.text()` instead of `.html()`

Or strip `<` and `>` from your characters array if you have to use `.html()`